# how to Import "XferMgrProgress" in Aws S3 java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use `TransferManager` in Aws s3 following [this guide](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html) from AWS documentation. However, I am not able to find the class `XferMgrProgress`. I tried searching for the class, but couldn't find any maven dependency for it.

Seems like this class is not available in S3 package of java SDK version I am using or we need to write our own class but this doesn't explain why AWS would show some our own class the example.

My current maven dependency is

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.741</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Edit**

I have found the source code of file [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=awsdocs%2Faws-doc-sdk-examples%2Faws-doc-sdk-examples-master%2Fjava%2Fexample_code%2Fs3%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Faws%2Fexample%2Fs3%2FXferMgrProgress.java) and copies it for now as a word around. However, it seems like it's a non-standard class and used only in one of the examples of AWS. But I am not sure why it is not part of standard SDK, after all, it's some pretty cool stuff.

However, if anyone of you finds it's maven dependency, it will be a great help.

Comment: So far I can understand it's a class which is not a standard part of java SDK, I need to write my own show progress class. If anyone finds if this is standard part of java SDK please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a class used in an example by AWS and found in package `package AWS.example.s3;`. It is not included in the standard S3 library which I don't know why. It is a cool class and provides a view regarding the progress of upload/ download.
It could have been useful to people.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I do not need XferMgrProgress to do some basic things. If you look at its source code, you can see it calls methods on `Transfer`:

e.g.

```java
xfer.waitForCompletion();
```